# Problema con notificaciones en base de datos y work:queue laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, base-de-datos, jobs, notification

Necesito enviar una notificación a base de datos 3 meses después de que mi usuario es registrado, usé el método delay de laravel, cree mi tabla de jobs con **php artisan queue:table** cambie el drive a **QUEUE_DRIVER=database** y ejecuté este comando **php artisan queue:work**, el problema es que cuando envío la notificación es procesada por el queue:work en la terminal pero no la guarda en la base de datos en la tabla de jobs, para hacer pruebas el tiempo de delay lo puse en 5 minutos, pero aún cuando pasa el tiempo no recibo la notificación.

Si el queue:work está apagado las notificaciones si se guardan en la base de datos, pero al encender el queue:work las procesa y se borran de la base pero aunque pasen los 5 minutos no las envía, adjunto el código de mi notificación y el delay en mi controller:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class DocReception extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    protected $message;

    use Queueable;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($message)
    {   
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {   


        return ['database'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return $this->message->toArray();
    }
}
```

```
$hora= now()->subHour(5);
$hora->addMinutes(5);

        $collection = collect([
            'date' => $date3, 
            'message' => 'Falta un día para la entrega de documentos de '.$guard->name.' '.$guard->lastname.'.'
            ]);

            $users = User::select('id','name')->where('position','Recursos Humanos')->get();
            foreach($users as $user){

                $user->notify((new DocReception($collection))->delay($hora));
            }
```